# Changing key bindings in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to change the commands for setting bookmarks, listing them and finding them in emacs.
This is the emacs lisp code I have tried:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-z") (kbd "C-x r m"))
```

This is failing. What is the correct method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to define a key to do what some other key does, you want to do

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-z") (global-key-binding (kbd "C-x r m")))
```

If then you can rebind <kbd>C-x r m</kbd> to something else and <kbd>C-c C-z</kbd> will still be bound to `bookmark-set` (this is similar to file copying).

If, on the other hand, you want to make <kbd>C-c C-z</kbd> an *alias* for <kbd>C-x r m</kbd>, you need to use `function-key-map`:

```
(define-key function-key-map (kbd "C-c C-z") (kbd "C-x r m"))
```

in which case <kbd>C-c C-z</kbd> will be doing whatever <kbd>C-x r m</kbd> is doing even if you rebind the latter (this is similar to symbolic file links).

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of [`global-set-key`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html) needs to be the symbol of the function you want to run.  In your case, the command <kbd>`C-x r m`</kbd> ordinarily corresponds to the `bookmark-set` (I determined this by running <kbd>`C-x k C-x r m`</kbd>), so you should pass `'bookmark-set`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-z") 'bookmark-set)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of Emacs' extensive help system:

1. use <kbd>f1 f</kbd> with cursor on `global-set-key` to get information
   on how it should be called.
2. use <kbd>f1 k</kbd> to find out which command any shortcut or menu item calls
3. look the info page <kbd>f1 i</kbd> if you need more info.
   Use <kbd>g (info)</kbd> to learn how to use info.